# Vue.js object proxies: props not showing in Object.keys

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue.js proxies its objects to catch property accesses. I seem to have found a leak in the abstraction: `Object.keys` doesn't return props in the list of keys.

With the following Vue component:

```js
function callMe() {
  var comp = Vue.component("comp", {
    template: "<button @click='clickMe()'>xxx</button>",
    props: {
        label: String,
        cardId: String,
        collapsible: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
        collapsed: Boolean,
    },
    data() {
        console.log(Object.keys(this))
        console.log(this.collapsible)
        console.log(Object.keys(this).includes("collapsible"))
        return { isCollapsed: this.collapsed }
    },
    methods: {
       clickMe(){
         console.log(this)
       } 
    }

  })
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    template: "<comp></comp>",
  })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
 
 <button @click="clickMe()" >Click Me</button>

</div>
```

The console output is:

```
(29) ["_uid", "_isVue", "$options", "_renderProxy", "_self", "$parent", "$root", "$children", "$refs", "_watcher", "_inactive", "_directInactive", "_isMounted", "_isDestroyed", "_isBeingDestroyed", "_events", "_hasHookEvent", "_vnode", "_staticTrees", "$vnode", "$slots", "$scopedSlots", "_c", "$createElement", "$attrs", "$listeners", "_watchers", "_props", "toggleThis"]
true
false
```

(Interestingly, when I call the check later, the `isCollapsed` item is in the list. You'll also notice that `clickMe` method is also present. It seems that only props are left out.)

Why is this happening?

More generally, how does Vue's Proxy object emit a different set of keys than it can then access?

This is a problem for me because I'm trying something fancy with `pug-vdom` and that internally uses `Object.keys` to enumerate the variables to inject into the Pug template.

Is this a Vue bug?
Alternately, is it possible to access a list of props keys from the `this` object, and export an object whose keys contain the props as well?

**edit:** added a runnable code snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Kind of a pug-vdom bug. Non-enumerable properties are a thing, they don’t require proxies, and they aren’t included in `Object.keys`. Same with properties on an object’s prototype.

Comment: I mean, I don't think pug-vdom is at the stage where it would care to work with any random object someone passes them, I'll assume responsibility for passing weird things to the render method. Still, why would Vue make props non-enumerable? (thanks for a good keyword to search for though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys()` does not iterate over prototype properties.
Also child component is `inherited` from root component.
This means props & data fields must be inside `__proto__` of child components.

Hence if we do `Object.keys(this__proto__).includes("collapsible")` , it returns `true` in child component.

If you want to access those fields from child components then use `this.$props` and `this.$data` .

```js
function callMe() {
  var comp = Vue.component("comp", {
    template: "<button @click='clickMe()'>xxx</button>",
    props: {
        label: String,
        cardId: String,
        collapsible: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
        collapsed: Boolean,
    },
    data() {
        console.log('Inside Child:',Object.keys(this))
        console.log(this.collapsible)
        console.log(Object.keys(this.__proto__).includes("collapsible"))
        console.log(Object.keys(this).includes("collapsible"))
        return { isCollapsed: this.collapsed }
    },
    methods: {
       clickMe(){
         console.log(this)
       } 
    }

  })
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    template: "<comp></comp>",
    props:{
    jack:{
          type: Boolean,
          default: true
         }
    },
    data(){
      console.log('Inside parent:', this.jack)
      return {}
    }
  })
}
callMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
 
 <button @click="clickMe()" >Click Me</button>

</div>
```

Comment: It *doesn’t* return `true`, though, in the question…

Comment: Why do you think so? Can you see the snippet.

Comment: Because it says “the console output is … true false”, and the entire question is about why that is.

Comment: I replicated his code, but its not showing true false as collapsible key is present in the `this` object. you can see my snippet

Comment: Indeed I can, but “I can’t reproduce that” by itself isn’t really an answer.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe try with a component, as opposed to the root Vue app? I'm now checking if _that_ is  the difference or if we have different versions of Vue or something

Comment: You can check `this.$props` or `this._props` also if they contain the prop fields

Comment: edited the question to show the problem - it really is different in component vs root object

Comment: -matejclk @Ry- I think this is due to child inheriting from root component & Object.keys() don't iterate over the prototype properties.

Comment: @Helpinghand check [Vue github: /global-api/asset.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/global-api/assets.js#L22) and [Vue github: /global-api/extend.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/global-api/extend.js#L84)

Comment: @Sphinx thanks for the reference, that makes it clear.